# Pgfgantt: Change anchor for centering

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pgfgantt

I have a Gantt produced with `pgfgantt` package. However, when you try to center it centers the entire figure (including names of the tasks).

I would like to have the table centered, and then the names and other things floating relative to it.

I imagine that the `tikzpicture` has some type of anchor set in the center of the entire set of items to center the image. So, I was wondering if it is possible to shift that anchor to the center of the table, instead of the whole figure.

I went through the manual, but couldn't find information on this regard. I tried to show what I mean by "centering the table" in the figures below. Note that due to the crop I used to produce the image the margins are out, but imagine the margins around the caption of the image.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{ganttchart}{1}{12}
  \ganttbar{Task with really long name}{1}{2} \\
  \end{ganttchart}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Not centered on the table.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \hspace*{-40px}% manually adjusted
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{ganttchart}{1}{12}
  \ganttbar{Task with really long name}{1}{2} \\
  \end{ganttchart}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Kind of centered on the table.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a bit of a roundabout way. Put the whole `ganttchart` in a `pgfinterruptboundingbox` environment, which essentially means that it will not be considered when deciding the bounding box. Then add `canvas/.append style={alias=frame}` to the `ganttchart` options (see code below), and after the `ganttchart` environment set the bounding box explicitly with

```
\useasboundingbox (frame.south west) rectangle (frame.north east);
```

All of this needs to be inside a `tikzpicture` environment, though if you just have the `ganttchart` environment the surrounding `tikzpicture` is not required.

Also note that you don't want to have `\\` after the last `ganttbar`, as that creates some additional whitespace.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
  \begin{ganttchart}[canvas/.append style={alias=frame}]{1}{12}
  \ganttbar{Task with really long name}{1}{2} 
  \end{ganttchart}
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\useasboundingbox (frame.south west) rectangle (frame.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Not centered on the table.} % actually, it is
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the label into `\llap{...}` or `\makebox[0pt][r]{...}` to make it zero width and stick out to the left, and add `\centering` to your `figure`. The remaining 'uncenteredness' is probably due to the distance of the label to the box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{ganttchart}{1}{12}
      \ganttbar{\llap{Task with really long name}}{1}{2} \\
%      \ganttbar{\makebox[0pt][r]{Task with really long name}}{1}{2} \\
    \end{ganttchart}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Kind of centered on the table.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]